# Team tab is removed every time Excel 2010 is opened

Tags: excel, add-in

Using **Excel 2010** and **TFS 2010**. I've been using the "Team" tab in Excel for quite a while now (very useful!). Today, the "Refresh" took ages and I couldn't use Excel so I killed the process in Task Manager. I reopened Excel and the Team tab was missing. I added it back in **File** > **Options** > **Add Ins** > **Manage COM Add Ins** > Go > selected the **Team Foundation Add-In**  and the **Team** tab is back. I can create/view lists etc. However, when I close and reopen Excel the **Team** tab is missing again.

How do I make the **Team** tab stay on the ribbon bar even when closing & reopening Excel?

Comment: A workaround (if the load behavior is all right): http://superuser.com/questions/704739/add-ins-not-loaded-in-excel-when-started-via-opening-a-file.

Comment: I found a fix and posted it below. The tab hasn't disappeared since the fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By chance, I re-enabled it (after having to manually re-add the tab again).

Excel > File > Options > Add-Ins > Manage > Disabled Items > select items > click Enable.

As easy as that.

Comment: good that you came back and answered your own question after a while

Answer (score 22):

For **Excel 2013 x64** and **Visual Studio 2012**, I had to change `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\TFCOfficeShim.Connect.4\LoadBehavior` to **3** ([Load at startup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386106.aspx#LoadBehavior)).

I had previously disabled the add-in via the Excel COM Add-Ins dialog box. This changed the add-in load behavior to "do not load automatically". Attempting to re-enable the add-in through the dialog box now only changes it to "load on demand", which is only good for one session of Excel. There is an [issue logged in Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780972/excel-team-foundation-add-in-does-not-load-automatically-when-re-enabled) for this. Changing the registry manually works around the bug.

Comment: Can we propose making this the answer? This works fantastically well! Thanks!

Comment: This works for Office 365 also. The only difference is the version which is currently 15: Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\TFCOfficeShim.Connect.15

Answer (score 4):

I have had that same issue with TFS 2010 Office Add-in and Excel. The reason was because there were two TFS Office add-ins, the first version was for a 64 bit machine, while the other was for a 32 bit machine. So I removed both versions, restarted excel, and re-added the 32 bit version of the TFS add-in. I have had no issues since.

EDIT: My local machine is running Windows 7 64 bit and Excel 2010.

Comment: I've tried adding both (one at a time of course) closing & reopening but the Team tab is still missing. Might need to reboot and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Try removing all versions of the TFSOfficeAddin dll from excel, close excel and open the command line, re-register the 32 bit version of the DLL by using regsvr32. Finally, go back into excel and re-add the COM add in.

Comment: I've done this and the tab is still missing. Will probably have to reinstall Office to get it working again.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this myself. The registry setting looked okay, and there weren't any add-ins listed under Disabled Items.

I launched Excel as Administrator, deleted all instances of Team Foundation Add-in (I had 3), and then re-added the add-in. It was then correctly showing as "Load at Startup." I closed Excel and re-opened from my usual shortcut, and everything looked good.

There were a number of Excel restarts peppered into that process as I was very much guessing and checking, but I believe that it was the act of re-adding the add-in that ultimately resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had to remove the extension (listed as "Unloaded") from COM Add-Ins list and then add it again.

Follow the instructions below to manually add it to Excel:

**Navigate to Com Add-ins manager:**
File > Options > Add-Ins > set "Manage:" to "COM Add-ins" > Go...

**Add it again:**
Add... > "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Team Foundation Server\11.0\x86\TFSOfficeAdd-in.dll" > OK

**Restart Excel:** Confirm the "Team" tab appears on startup

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround that helps several people. This is not a fix but still has worth.

Launch Excel as Administrator.  You do this by right clicking the Excel Icon, then right click the Excel mini-icon then click "Run as administrator".

This is not a fix and can be a hassle but for many with this issue it will provide the features you want.  Hopefully Microsoft will come up with a permanent solution in the future.

[image: Run Excel as Admin]

Answer (score 0):

With latest versions this problem can be solved by installing **Azure DevOps Office® Integration 2019** from

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#other-family

[image]

If you don't see **Team Foundation Add in** you can use this method which saved a lot of time for me

it will appear like this , **file --> options --> add ins**

[image]